# In monodevelop how can I clear out the Task list?

Tags: monodevelop

My task list pad is filled with old //Todo comment tasks that have been parsed out of the code. Unfortunately the files they refer to have long since gone and the tasks are hanging around like zombies. Deleting each task simply throws an error that the file is missing. How can I manually force a complete cleanout of the tasks list so it can reparse? I had a quick look at the source code for this part of MD but I didn't see anything obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you [file a bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com).

However, for a quick workaround, try deleting the code completion database caches. On Mac you can find them in `~/Library/Caches/MonoDevelop-3.0/DerivedData`, and on Windows they're in `AppData\Local\MonoDevelop-3.0\Cache\DerivedData`.

Comment: Thanks! Even in 4.0.1 (bundled with Unity3D) I ran into this issue. Nowadays these caches are per Assembly.  So the file MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem.ProjectCommentTags.cache has be deleted in the affected assembly's directory.